# Por que usar StyleSheet.create?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Por que usar o `StyleSheet.create`? Ao iniciar um novo projeto (`react-native init test`, o projeto vem com o `style` da seguinte forma.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  Imagem: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  }
});
```

Porem se eu fizer da seguinte forma, o `style` vai funcionar da mesma forma, então qual a diferença?

```
const styles = {
  container: {

  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  Imagem: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: 50,
    height: 50
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu acho  melhor usar  `StyleSheet` sempre que possível porque você terá mais performance do que apenas usar objetos comuns.

Citação retirada da documentação do React :

> Criar uma folha de estilo a partir de um objeto de estilo (**Stylesheet**) torna possível se referir a ele por ID em vez de criar um novo objeto de estilo sempre.
>
> Ele(**Stylesheet**) também permite enviar o estilo apenas uma vez. Todas as utilizações subsequentes vão encaminhar um id (não implementado ainda).

Espero que ajude!